# switchMap to keep/cancel request with angular http client

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, angular-httpclient, ngrx-effects

I have some ngrx effects that resembles

```
effect1 = this.actions$.pipe(
 ofType('x'), 
 switchMap(data => this.httpClient.post(data)), 
 map(result => new mappedAction(result))
);
```

For effect1, when a new trigger is received, I want to forget and cancel the previous request, cancel it. I read a bit about it and it seems this is what switchMap on httpClient requests does anyways.

For another effect2, let's assume, when a new trigger is received, I do not care about the result of the previous request, but I care that the request completes. What should I use in place of switchMap?

Comment: that does not work? it should not require more if I'm not mistaken. btw. I assume 'x' is just placeholder and usually there is real type - becouse with 'x' there might be some typo or sth

Comment: There are two scenarios, in one case I want to cancel the previous xhr, in another case I do not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement a custom operator that works similar to `mergeMap` but only emits items of the last Observable you mapped to.

```js
function mergeMapLast<T, R>(next: ((data: T) => Observable<R>)): OperatorFunction<T, R> {
  return (source: Observable<T>) => defer(() => {
    let curr = 0;
    return source.pipe(
      mergeMap((data, index) => {
        curr = index;
        return next(data).pipe(filter(_ => index === curr));
      })
    );
  });
}
```

Usage

```
effect2 = this.actions$.pipe(
 ofType('x'), 
 mergeMapLast(data => this.httpClient.post(data)), 
 map(result => new mappedAction(result))
);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-vu2gfp

Comment: Nice approach, is `defer` required though?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Yes, `defer` is used so that different subscribers each get their own instance of `curr`. Otherwise they would share that variable.

Answer (score 3):

In that case you should use [`mergeMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html):

```
effect2 = this.actions$.pipe(
 ofType('x'),
 // inner subscription is not completed on source emition (many subscriptions allowed)
 // but the order in which they complete is not mantained
 mergeMap(data => this.httpClient.post(data)), 
 map(result => new mappedAction(result))
);
```

If in your case, the order is important, you should use `concatMap`.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware using `switchMap` for server side mutation. In effect1, due to the post request, it seems like that you are doing a server side mutation on some resources. You need to be assure that even though the request is canceled on client side it is still handled by the backend.

For effect2 you have 2 options from my point of view.

```
ConcatMap
```

ConcatMap takes the trigger as input parameter and will perform your http request. If there is a new trigger while the http request is still ongoing this trigger will be buffered until the inner observable (http) completes. Depending on your situation this might lead to a memory overflow. E.g the request takes 10 seconds to complete but this effect is triggered every 100ms. All this triggers will be cached and performed sequentielly.

```
MergeMap
```

MergeMap isn’t caching the triggers. It is just subscribing to the inner observable as soon as the action is triggered. But it might be the case that the inner observable take a different amount of time, e.g first http request takes 20 seconds and the second http request just 1 second. In this case the further steps in the operator chain for the 2nd http request would be performed before the first http request even completes. This might be an issue if the order of execution is important for you.

Do note that all of those operators will emit the http response as result. You could potentially use something like if you would like to forward the trigger value when the http request completes

```
this.action().pipe(
   concatMap(x => 
       forkJoin([of(x), this.http(...)]).pipe(
           map(([x]) => x)
       )
    )
 );
```

Sorry for bad indention, I hope it works, it is actually not tested and written on my phone. When there is any issues with the code snippets, just let me know, I can improve them later on.